# How to get coordinates about a point in Google Maps API iOS?

Tags: ios, api, google-maps, xamarin.ios, xamarin

How I can get the coordinates (CLLocationCoordinate2D) of a PointF in Google maps API Xamarin for iOS

previously used:

```
PointF location = reticula.Center;                  
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = MapaApple.ConvertPoint (location, this.View);
```

CLLocationCoordinate2D I did return, but now with google API

I use something like this:

```
PointF location = reticula.Center;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (MapaGoogle.ConvertPointFromView(CLLocation,this.View);
```

But one PointF me back.

I need CLLocationCoordinate2D any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = mapView.Projection.CoordinateForPoint(location);
```

Note: The point should be relative to the map view.